# What does function ROOT4146650865 mean in PancakeSwap contract?

Tags: bsc

I have come across this transaction during some research:
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xc50d038ab44b6b158a7431d25400e482775e2c70194f2a6e1aafe8bf3b5caefc

It has the following input:

```
Function: ROOT4146650865() ***

00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001d1d815e76cc9dcdf7
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000032de242d38985ceb
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0
0000000000000000000000007e2098ee0d2471bb50dc0a811e98a66083b4bf2a
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000061ddad21
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
000000000000000000000000b9b280f4277b49d59ac15283b6ae00a90aac5415
000000000000000000000000bb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c
```

It does not have the first 4 bytes for function selector. So the questions are:

1. What does such a call mean?
2. What is executed if it is successful?
3. What is the best way to recognize such calls? Is it just `MOD(input.length, 64) == 0` or is there a more explicit flag?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bscscan bug if you switch the view to "original" it will show the whole input data:

> 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001d1d815e76cc9dcdf700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000032de242d38985ceb00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a00000000000000000000000007e2098ee0d2471bb50dc0a811e98a66083b4bf2a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000061ddad210000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000b9b280f4277b49d59ac15283b6ae00a90aac5415000000000000000000000000bb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c

It is using the first 4 bytes `00000000` as the function selector. If you look it in the [Ethereum Signatures Database](https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=00000000) it will show several function that have the same signature.

- ROOT4146650865()
- blockHashAskewLimitary(uint256)
- cehbdjakgfi(address,address,uint256,uint8)

It is likely a transaction sent to the wrong contract, or wrongly formatted transaction.